# C++ Sockets,Multithreading and output handling

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, output, cout

I want to make chat system.It should write You: and then anything you type and whenever you get text from other user,just delete You: type User: message and You: again.

Server:

```
        std::cin.ignore();
        std::thread t1(readData,&acceptedSocket);
        do{
            memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
            std::cout << "You: ";
            std::cin.getline(buffer,255);
            n = send(acceptedSocket,buffer,strlen(buffer),0);
        }while(n > 0);
```

Client:

```
    std::cin.ignore();
    std::thread t1(readData,&connectingSocket);
    do{
        memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
        std::cout << "You: ";
        std::cin.getline(buffer,255);
        n = send(connectingSocket,buffer,strlen(buffer),0);
    }while(n > 0);
```

ReadData:

```
void readData(int *socketPointer){
    int connectingSocket = *socketPointer;
    char buffer[256];
    memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
    while(recv(connectingSocket,buffer,255,0)){
        std::cout << "\b\b\b\b\bUSER:" << buffer << std::endl << "You: ";
        memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
    }
}
```

Output:

Server:

```
USER:Hello
USER:How are u doing
Hi
You: You: I am fine
USER:gg
wp
You: You:
```

Client:

```
You: Hello
You: How are u doing
USER:Hi
USER:I am fine
gg
You: USER:wp
```

Wannable Server output:

```
USER:Hello
USER:How are u doing
You: Hi
You: I am fine
USER:gg
You: wp
You:
```

Wannable Client output:

```
You: Hello
You: How are u doing
USER:Hi
USER:I am fine
You: gg
USER:wp
You:
```

It seems that you can't put new line character while there is cin getting a line in other thread.Thank you!

Comment: The c++ `iostream`s are meant for only simple input/output operations. If you want to do more complex manipulation of your output, you should look into using a library like [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer!
I noticed that when two threads are running - one is getting line from cin stream and the other is putting out text,you need to flush cout buffer,so only text appears only after std::endl,which flushes the buffer and puts the new line at the same time so:

```
std::cout.flush():
```

Fixed the problem:

```
    std::cout << "\b\b\b\b\bUSER:" << buffer << std::endl << "You: ";
    std::cout.flush();
```